# Detecting SD card corruption

Tags: linux, sd-card, file-corruption

Is there any way I can detect the SD card corruption at run time?

I have a situation where in firmware upgrade is affected because of SD card issue, however it will be known only after the upgrade fails. What I am looking for is the tests/any utilities which can be used to detect the SD card corruption on the go. Say, I run a check every day to see is if SD card fine or has corrupted? If corrupted, I can stall the upgrade and recommend SD card replacement or to take some other action.

Any input is greatly appreciated. Achieving this without physically removing the SD card will be good.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in only detecting corruption, then you can use a `*sum` utility, like `sha256sum`.

From within the directory to protect, run the following. Note the use of `find ... -print0` and `xargs -0` to accommodate paths with spaces or other special characters.

```
find . -type f -print0 \
    | xargs -0 sha256sum \
    > manifest.sum
```

Then use the following to validate the file content.

```
sha256sum -c manifest.sum
```

The output will list files with `OK` or `FAILED`, and the return value will be `0` (zero) if all files checked out ok, or non-zero if there were errors.

This process will validate all files under the current directory, and leave `manifest.sum` behind.

Ideally, you would generate `manifest.sum` at the source (e.g: at build time), and distribute it with the files - only running the verification (`sha256sum -c`) on the target device.

---

As you have mentioned that this is for a firmware update process, I would recommend that you look further than just verifying the data for corruption.

In many cases, it is beneficial to ensure that the upgrade being applied is genuine, and has been provided by the intended source... If you allow any upgrade to be applied to a system, then you open it up for accidental (and potentially damaging) updates as well as malicious updates.

To address this, you should look into cryptographically signing the update.

- You *could* get away with signing just the `manifest.sum` produced above (less processing overhead). By signing the checksums you can verify the content of each file... presuming that the digest is secure of course... ([MD5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Security) would not be a good choice)
- However it might be better to distribute an archive that is signed (and possibly encrypted) in full and verified before it is even extracted.

As the output of the `*sum` utilities are ASCII text, you could use `gpg --clearsign` to sign the data:

```
find . -type f -print0 \
    | xargs -0 sha256sum \
    | gpg --clearsign --default-key 7826F053 \
    > manifest.asc
```

On the target, you can then verify the signature:

```
gpg --verify manifest.asc
```

Then if, **and only if**, the signature is valid and from an expected origin (you'll need to use `--status-fd` to verify this), you can move on to verify the file content:

```
gpg --decrypt manifest.asc \
    | sha256sum -c -
```

Note that `*sum` must be at the "*end*" of the pipeline to ensure that you see the return code... alternatively you could use `set -o pipefail`

---

I mentioned using `--status-fd` above... it gets messy in the shell, so you will probably want to write an application to handle this more sanely... Something like this will "*work*" (i.e: prove a point).

The fingerprint of the key used to sign the manifest is: `A5C929D6A230C02067720F1DB2B38B43C2ABEB33`.

```
gpg --status-fd 3 --verify manifest.asc 3>&1 1>/dev/null \
    | grep -Eq '^\[GNUPG:\] VALIDSIG A5C929D6A230C02067720F1DB2B38B43C2ABEB33 '
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of detecting corruption depends (a bit) on how the SD card was originally formatted, but you could try running fdisk on it or badblock. See [Verify if the micro SD is corrupt](https://help.endian.com/hc/en-us/articles/218146758-Verify-if-the-micro-SD-card-is-corrupt):

> You should use the command badblocks for this purpose, using the options -n (to specify that the check is carried out in read-write, non-destructive mode) and -v (verbose mode). Make sure that the partitions you want to check are NOT mounted

at the command prompt, type: mount 
and look for the device entry that corresponds to your SD card. If it is listed, then you must first unmount the filesystems:

```
$ sudo umount /dev/sde1
```

then type

```
$ sudo badblocks -n -v /dev/sde
```

or

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sde1
```

Note that badblocks can take a very long time. I would try fsck first

Comment: Please include important steps from your link in your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: With most filesystems this will miss _any_ / _all_ corruption that hits file content but misses the filesystem metadata.

Comment: @Attie -- that's a good point, Using a check sum as xenoid suggested would handle the corruption within file content.

Comment: Using fsck and badblocks seem to work fine. It could not detect any error and operation completed. Even after these showed everything normal, I had a different problem. Suppose I create a new file inside SD card and then unmount and mount it back, that new file created does not exists after mount! Similarly, I have deleted an existing file from SD card and did unmount and mount back. Deleted file appeared again after mount! How this could happen? Is this also a SD card corruption? How to detect this condition before-hand?

Answer (score 0):

- Compute the MD5 of the files and store it on the card:

  ```
  md5sum * >SDCardFiles.md5
  ```
- To check use `md5um` in "check" mode (it will recompute the MD5 of the files on the card and compare with the MD5 stored in the file).

  ```
  md5sum -c SDCardFiles.md5
  ```

Note: you have to be in the same directory when you run the initial `md5sum` and the `md5sum -c` since the path to the files is kept in the `.md5` file.